# Cannot create new table after running migration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel i have created a new model for Admin and added migration file for the admin but when i run migration command it does not generate table for Admin but generate remaining migration i.e. for user and password reset are being generated. I have tried php artisan migrate:refresh command but it did not work. Running php artisan migrate:status shows all the tables. Please help to sort out my issue.

My code is :

> 2019_05_11_083510_create_admins_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

> Model: Admin.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: any error you got ???

Comment: No it does not generate any error

Comment: what do you mean? finally it's getting a message to you like `nothing to migrate` or `error this table is already exists` and ... , what is the message after you run php artisan:migrate ???

Comment: migration table created successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like there is already an entry into your migrations table, and 'migrate:fresh' for some reason isn't working or you tried 'migrate:refresh' instead by accident.

### Ideas

So the first things I could think to try:

- You said 'php artisan migrate:refresh' try doing 'php artisan migrate:fresh'.
- If the migrate:fresh doesnt work go into your SQL and edit the migrations table and delete the entry for the migrations you want to run, then run 'php artisan migrate'.
- If none of the above work you could try doing a 'php artisan optimize', this will clear all cache for everything and as well as run you through the errors it finds.

Hope this answered your question, good luck!